# Deleting temp files when loading program with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Basically, the very first time I run the program, it will create temp files and save into the folder, and then the program will restart `application.restart()`. After the program restarted, it will look for the temp files and do something. My question is: Is there a way to clear temp files when the very first time I run the program. Thanks

Comment: What file(s)? According to what you said, they don't exist until the first time you run it. After all, isn't that how you KNOW it is the first time?  There is no COUNT that says how many times your application was run.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create file storing its creation time and do the clear file thing and reset the time if its stored time is too old (over than 1 minute before). 
Inside "My Project>Appliation>View Application Events" (ApplicationEvents.vb), inside the MyApplication class, insert these:

```
Public Sub Me_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
Dim date As Integer() = Val(New Sysem.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData,
"time.txt")).ReadLine.Split({"/"c," "c,":"c}))
Dim time As New DateTime(date(0),date(1),date(2),date(3),date(4),date(5))
If time.AddMinutes(1).CompareTo(My.Computer.Clock.GmtTime) > 0 Then
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData)
' Create your temp files
' Write them into My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData,
"time.txt"),My.Computer.Clock.GmtTime.ToString, False)
Application.Restart()
' It will pass onto your main code after this
End If
End Sub
```